# How to Explicit event accessors

Tags: c#, events

Here is a sketch of explicit event assessors:

```
delegate void EventHandler (SomeObject m, EventArgs e);
EventHandler _priceChanged; //Private Delegate
public event EventHandler PriceChanged
{
    add {_priceChanged += value;}
    remove {_priceChanged -= value;}
}
```

- Apparently the difference between this and the standard implementation is that the use of the delegate is not thread-safe. How do I make this thread-safe?
- How do I allow things like :

  ```
  if (PriceChanged != null)...   etc
  ```

Comment: How do I allow things like : `if (PriceChanged != null)...   etc`. You can't, not on the eventhandler declaration level - this always needs to be done in the code calling this. Hava a look at reactive extensions if you want an alternative - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh242982%28v=vs.103%29.aspx.

Comment: @decPL Are you sure? (_priceChanged != null) is valid, and I'd expect properties to allow you to do things like this through them. Is add and remove all you can do then without RX?

Comment: It is obviously valid, just not something that can be done using explicit event accessors - for example - one reason for _priceChanged to be null is if neither add nor remove was ever called - how could they prevent the null exception then? Unless you want to initialize your delegate collection with a dummy callback, but that's just evil. I'm not sure what you meant by your last question - yes, add and remove are the explicit accessors, same as get and set for properties - both cases are useful, but both have limitations.

Comment: Okay, thanks very much. I'd consider that an up-votable answer if you want. bit disappointing that I can't interact with PriceChanged  like its _priceChanged, but I did see this coming and I do see why.

Comment: and in case you're wondering why have them in the first place if those are limited - some bedtime read: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163533.aspx

Comment: @decPL Thanks for the link. Somewhat amusingly I posted that link as well in a comment I deleted. Oh, well, I'll go read the whole thing now I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 delegate void EventHandler (SomeObject m, EventArgs e);
 EventHandler _priceChanged; //Private Delegate
 private Object _myLock = new Object();

 public event EventHandler PriceChanged
 {
    add {
       lock(_myLock)
       {_priceChanged += value;}
    }
    remove {
       lock(_myLock)
       {_priceChanged -= value;} 
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

> - Apparently the difference between this and the standard implementation is that the use of the delegate is not thread-safe. How do I make this thread-safe?

Refer to Shai's answer.

> - How do I allow things like :

```
if (PriceChanged != null)...   etc
```

You can't, not on the eventhandler declaration level - this always needs to be done in the code calling this.
Just to give an example: one reason for `_priceChanged` to be null is if neither add nor remove was ever called - how could they prevent the null exception then? Unless you want to initialize your delegate collection with a dummy callback, but that's just evil.

Have a look at [reactive extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh242982%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) if you want an alternative.